# With NBuilder for .NET, what's the difference between .Has(..) and .Have(..)?

Tags: c#, .net, nbuilder

[NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/) has two of the following fluent methods

```
.Has(..)
.Have(..)
```

eg.

```
return Builder<User>.CreateListOfSize(100)
    .WhereTheFirst(1)
        .Has(x => x.FirstName = "Jon Skeet")
    .Build();

return Builder<User>.CreateListOfSize(100)
    .WhereTheFirst(1)
        .Have(x => x.FirstName = "Jon Skeet")
    .Build();
```

I don't understand the difference? Can someone please explain why I would do a Have instead of Has .. or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are identical. Full source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/nbuilder/source/browse/trunk/Source/FizzWare.NBuilder/OperableExtensions.cs).

**Has:**

```
    [Obsolete(Messages.NewSyntax_UseWith)]
    public static IOperable<T> Has<T, TFunc>(this IOperable<T> operable, Func<T, TFunc> func)
    {
        return With(operable, func);
    }
```

**Have:**

```
    [Obsolete(Messages.NewSyntax_UseWith)]
    public static IOperable<T> Have<T, TFunc>(this IOperable<T> operable, Func<T, TFunc> func)
    {
        return With(operable, func);
    }
```

Comment: Cheers :) ... (now lets make things confusing, eh?) :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason there was `Has` and `Have` was to provide a fluent syntax in two different uses.

For example, `Has` makes sense in this case:

```
Builder<User>.CreateListOfSize(100)
    .WhereTheFirst(1)
        .Has(x => x.FirstName = "Jon Skeet")
    .Build();
```

While, `Have` makes sense in this case:

```
Builder<User>.CreateListOfSize(100)
    .WhereAll()
        .Have(x => x.FirstName = "Jon Skeet")
    .Build();
```

Recently, however, it was recognized that the syntax needed to be cleaned up to prevent confusion due to differences in the syntax when creating lists vs single objects.

So now you can do the following:

```
Builder<User>.CreateListOfSize(100)
    .All()
        .With(x => x.FirstName = "Jon")
    .TheFirst(1)
        .With(x => x.LastName = "Skeet")
    .Build();
```

...hopefully that should be less confusing going forward.

also, you'll notice in the answer given by ClosureCowboy that the `Has` and `Have` extensions had already been marked as Obsolete when he answered...

Comment: Thanks :) and yeah .. it was a while ago since i posted this question and i've updated all my projects to use `All` and `With` in recent months, etc. But thanks for properly answering the question, though :)